# How canI make a JLabel be right justified in a box container?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, layout-manager, boxlayout

I have a vertical Box I call parent. I add a JLable, then a JTextArea.
Next
Next I create  two vertical Box containers called right and left Next I add 2 JLables to them and put the two box containers in a horizontal Box called Bot.  Bot gets added to the parent box I first created

These two labels are drawn next to each other, in the center. The first one is drawn left justified, the second one is right justified.

I want them both right justified so they wont be next to each other
code
CODE

```
Box boxParent = Box.createVerticalBox();
      String indName="test";
      String indDescription="Description";

      Box boxTitle = Box.createHorizontalBox();
      boxTitle.add(new JLabel(" Indicater:"));
      boxTitle.add(new JLabel(in    dName));
      boxParent.add(boxTitle);

      JTextArea description = new JTextArea(indDescription,5,2);
      boxParent.add(description);

      Box bot= Box.createHorizontalBox();
      Box right = Box.createVerticalBox();
      right.add(new JLabel("right"));
      right.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
      Box left = Box.createVerticalBox();
      left.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
      left.add(new JLabel("left"));
      bot.add(right);
      bot.add(left);

      boxParent.add(bot);
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want them both right justified so they wont be next to each other code CODE

Not sure I understand your requirement. They both can't be right justified since they are on the same line.

If you want space between the two components maybe you want:

```
  bot.add(right);
  bot.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
  bot.add(left);
```